# window.open global scope variable javascript

Tags: javascript, global, window.open

Can anyone tell me how i could use a global scope variable so that I could close "window 1" from "window2"?This is really throwing me for a loop, so any help would be great!

I have index.html with 1 link and 1 button. Button opens window 1, link opens window 2. I want Window 2 to have a button that can close window 1. Please help if you can!! Thanks!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin1()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','');
myWindow.document.write("<p><img src=\"flower.jpg\" /></p>");
myWindow.focus();
}
function openWin2()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','');
myWindow.document.write("<style type=\"text/css\">body{background-color:yellow;}</style>
<p><img src=\"bee.jpg\" /></p><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.close();\" 
value=\"Close Window 1\" />");
myWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="Window 1" onclick="openWin1();" /><br />
<a href="javascript:openWin2();">Window 2</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested this locally (works in Chrome, should work in other browsers too):

```
function openWin1() {
    myWindow1 = window.open('google.com', '', '');
    myWindow1.document.write("<p><img src=\"flower.jpg\" /></p>");
    myWindow1.focus();
}

function openWin2() {
    myWindow2 = window.open('yahoo.com', '', '');
    myWindow2.document.write("<style type=\"text/css\">body{background-color:yellow;}</style><p><img src=\"bee.jpg\"></p><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.opener.myWindow1.opener = window.self;window.opener.myWindow1.close();\" value=\"Close Window 1\" />");
    myWindow2.focus();
}
```

Comment: it will close the parent window not his sibling

Comment: I see. Thanks for the eye opener.

Answer (score 0):

use `window.opener.mywindow.close()` from second window to close first . Choose other variable name for second window object

Comment: mmmm.. yes, i've tried that. doesn't seem to work. maybe i was doing it wrong? suggestions anyone?

Comment: window.opener.mywindow.close() is not working. Don't think so. It must work. Remember to create different variable for both window

Answer (score 0):

Both "window1" and "window2" can refer to the original page via `window.opener`. Your original page can therefore expose a global function that either of the other pages can call like this:

```
window.opener.closeTheOtherOne();
```